# What are the options for storing hierarchical data in a relational database?

Tags: sql, database, tree, relational-database, hierarchical-data

**Good Overviews**

Generally speaking, you're making a decision between fast read times (for example, nested set) or fast write times (adjacency list). Usually, you end up with a combination of the options below that best fit your needs. The following provides some in-depth reading:

- [One more Nested Intervals vs. Adjacency List comparison](http://vadimtropashko.wordpress.com/2008/08/09/one-more-nested-intervals-vs-adjacency-list-comparison/): *the best comparison* of Adjacency List, Materialized Path, Nested Set, and Nested Interval I've found.
- [Models for hierarchical data](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data): slides with good explanations of tradeoffs and example usage
- [Representing hierarchies in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/): very good overview of Nested Set in particular
- [Hierarchical data in RDBMSs](http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/links/#hierarchical): a most comprehensive and well-organized set of links I've seen, but not much in the way of explanation

**Options**

Ones I am aware of and general features:

1. [Adjacency List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list):

- Columns: ID, ParentID
- Easy to implement.
- Cheap node moves, inserts, and deletes.
- Expensive to find the level, ancestry & descendants, path
- Avoid N+1 via [Common Table Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_table_expressions) in databases that support them

2. [Nested Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) (a.k.a [Modified Preorder Tree Traversal (MPTT)](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2016/01/04/modified-preorder-tree-traversal-django/))

- Columns: Left, Right
- Cheap ancestry, descendants
- Very expensive `O(n/2)` moves, inserts, deletes due to volatile encoding

3. [Bridge Table](https://www.informationweek.com/software/information-management/kimball-university-five-alternatives-for-better-employee-dimension-modeling/d/d-id/1082326) (a.k.a. [Closure Table /w triggers](http://dirtsimple.org/2010/11/simplest-way-to-do-tree-based-queries.html))

- Uses separate join table with ancestor, descendant, depth (optional)
- Cheap ancestry and descendants
- Writes costs `O(log n)` (size of the subtree) for insert, updates, deletes
- Normalized encoding: good for RDBMS statistics & query planner in joins
- Requires multiple rows per node

4. [Lineage Column](https://web.archive.org/web/20150909165001/http://www.ferdychristant.com/blog//articles/DOMM-7QJPM7) (a.k.a. [Materialized Path](http://communities.bmc.com/communities/docs/DOC-9902), Path Enumeration)

- Column: lineage (e.g. /parent/child/grandchild/etc...)
- Cheap descendants via prefix query (e.g. `LEFT(lineage, #) = '/enumerated/path'`)
- Writes costs `O(log n)` (size of the subtree) for insert, updates, deletes
- Non-relational: relies on Array datatype or serialized string format

5. [Nested Intervals](https://sigmodrecord.org/publications/sigmodRecord/0506/p47-article-tropashko.pdf)

- Like nested set, but with real/float/decimal so that the encoding isn't volatile (inexpensive move/insert/delete)
- Has real/float/decimal representation/precision issues
- [Matrix encoding variant](http://vadimtropashko.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/ch5.pdf) adds ancestor encoding (materialized path) for "free", but with the added trickiness of linear algebra.

6. [Flat Table](http://evolt.org/node/4047)

- A modified Adjacency List that adds a Level and Rank (e.g. ordering) column to each record.
- Cheap to iterate/paginate over
- Expensive move and delete
- Good Use: threaded discussion - forums / blog comments

7. [Multiple lineage columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6802687/684229)

- Columns: one for each lineage level, refers to all the parents up to the root, levels down from the item's level are set to NULL
- Cheap ancestors, descendants, level
- Cheap insert, delete, move of the leaves
- Expensive insert, delete, move of the internal nodes
- Hard limit to how deep the hierarchy can be

**Database Specific Notes**

*MySQL/MariaDB*

- <strike>[Use session variables for Adjacency List](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/29/adjacency-list-vs-nested-sets-mysql/)</strike>
- Use CTEs in MySQL 8.0 or MariaDB 10.2

*Oracle*

- Use [CONNECT BY](http://www.ypl.com/oracle/sql/hierarchical_queries/html_deep/index.html) to traverse Adjacency Lists

*PostgreSQL*

- [ltree datatype](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ltree.html) for Materialized Path

*SQL Server*

- [General summary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc794278.aspx)
- 2008 offers [HierarchyId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx) data type that appears to help with the Lineage Column approach and expand the depth that can be represented.

Comment: According to http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-antipatterns-strike-back page 77, `Closure Tables` are superior to `Adjacency List`, `Path Enumeration` and `Nested Sets` in terms of ease of use (and I'm guessing performance as well).

Comment: I miss a very simple version here: a simple BLOB. 

If your hierarchy only has a few dozend items a serialized tree of id's might be the best option.

Comment: @Lothar: question is a community wiki so feel free to have at it. My thought in that regard is I would only do it with those databases that support some sort of blob structuring such as XML with a stable query language such as XPATH. Otherwise I don't see a good way of querying aside from retrieve, deserialize, and munge in code, not SQL. And if you really have a problem where you need a lot of arbitrary elements you might be better off using Node database like Neo4J, which I've used and liked, albeit never taken through to production.

Comment: For MS SQL Server: [Combination of Id-ParentId and HierarchyId Approaches to Hierarchical Data](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1192607/Combination-of-Id-ParentId-and-HierarchyId)

Comment: That MSDN link for "General Summary" no longer shows the article. It was in the September 2008 edition of MSDN Magazine, which you can download as a CHM file, or see via the web archive at: https://web.archive.org/web/20080913041559/http://msdn.microsoft.com:80/en-us/magazine/cc794278.aspx

Answer (score 105):

My favorite answer is as what the first sentence in this thread suggested.  Use an Adjacency List to maintain the hierarchy and use Nested Sets to query the hierarchy.

The problem up until now has been that the coversion method from an Adjacecy List to Nested Sets has been frightfully slow because most people use the extreme RBAR method known as a "Push Stack" to do the conversion and has been considered to be way to expensive to reach the Nirvana of the simplicity of maintenance by the Adjacency List and the awesome performance of Nested Sets.  As a result, most people end up having to settle for one or the other especially if there are more than, say, a lousy 100,000 nodes or so.  Using the push stack method can take a whole day to do the conversion on what MLM'ers would consider to be a small million node hierarchy.

I thought I'd give Celko a bit of competition by coming up with a method to convert an Adjacency List to Nested sets at speeds that just seem impossible. Here's the performance of the push stack method on my i5 laptop.

```
Duration for     1,000 Nodes = 00:00:00:870 
Duration for    10,000 Nodes = 00:01:01:783 (70 times slower instead of just 10)
Duration for   100,000 Nodes = 00:49:59:730 (3,446 times slower instead of just 100) 
Duration for 1,000,000 Nodes = 'Didn't even try this'
```

And here's the duration for the new method (with the push stack method in parenthesis).

```
Duration for     1,000 Nodes = 00:00:00:053 (compared to 00:00:00:870)
Duration for    10,000 Nodes = 00:00:00:323 (compared to 00:01:01:783)
Duration for   100,000 Nodes = 00:00:03:867 (compared to 00:49:59:730)
Duration for 1,000,000 Nodes = 00:00:54:283 (compared to something like 2 days!!!)
```

Yes, that's correct.  1 million nodes converted in less than a minute and 100,000 nodes in under 4 seconds.

You can read about the new method and get a copy of the code at the following URL.
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Hierarchy/94040/

I also developed a "pre-aggregated" hierarchy using similar methods.  MLM'ers and people making bills of materials will be particularly interested in this article.
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/94570/

If you do stop by to take a look at either article, jump into the "Join the discussion" link and let me know what you think.

Comment: MLM = "Multi-Level Marketing".  Amway, Shaklee, ACN, etc, etc.

Comment: Update.  The conversion process from Adjacency List to Nested Sets for 1 million nodes takes only about 19 seconds on a good 64 bit machine without any code changes.

Answer (score 43):

### Adjacency Model + Nested Sets Model

I went for it because I could insert new items to the tree easily (you just need a branch's id to insert a new item to it) and also query it quite fast.

```
+-------------+----------------------+--------+-----+-----+
| category_id | name                 | parent | lft | rgt |
+-------------+----------------------+--------+-----+-----+
|           1 | ELECTRONICS          |   NULL |   1 |  20 |
|           2 | TELEVISIONS          |      1 |   2 |   9 |
|           3 | TUBE                 |      2 |   3 |   4 |
|           4 | LCD                  |      2 |   5 |   6 |
|           5 | PLASMA               |      2 |   7 |   8 |
|           6 | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS |      1 |  10 |  19 |
|           7 | MP3 PLAYERS          |      6 |  11 |  14 |
|           8 | FLASH                |      7 |  12 |  13 |
|           9 | CD PLAYERS           |      6 |  15 |  16 |
|          10 | 2 WAY RADIOS         |      6 |  17 |  18 |
+-------------+----------------------+--------+-----+-----+
```

- Every time you need all children of any parent you just query the `parent` column.
- If you needed all descendants of any parent you query for items which have their `lft` between `lft` and `rgt` of parent.
- If you needed all parents of any node up to the root of the tree, you query for items having `lft` lower than the node's `lft` and `rgt` bigger than the node's `rgt` and sort the by `parent`.

**I needed to make accessing and querying the tree faster than inserts, that's why I chose this**

The only problem is to fix the `left` and `right` columns when inserting new items. well I created a stored procedure for it and called it every time I inserted a new item which was rare in my case but it is really fast.
I got the idea from the Joe Celko's book, and the stored procedure and how I came up with it is explained here in DBA SE
https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/89051/41481

Although this solution allows for rapid searches to locate descendants, it is not ideal for handling large datasets that require frequent inserts or deletes due to its slow performance in these operations. Therefore, it is best suited for tables that won't chnage frequently.

Comment: +1 this is a legit approach. From my own experience the key is deciding if you are OK with dirty reads when large update operations occur. If not, it becomes a matter or preventing people from querying tables directly and always going through an API - DB sprocs / functions or code.

Comment: This is an interesting solution; however, I am not sure querying the parent column really offers any major advantage when attempting to find children -- that's why we have left and right columns, in the first place.

Comment: @Thomas, there is a difference between `children` and `descendants`. `left` and `right` are used to find the descendants.

Answer (score 41):

This design was not mentioned yet:

### [Multiple lineage columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6802687/684229)

Though it has limitations, if you can bear them, it's very simple and very efficient. Features:

- Columns: one for each lineage level, refers to all the parents up to the root, levels below the current items' level are set to 0 (or NULL)
- There is a fixed limit to how deep the hierarchy can be
- Cheap ancestors, descendants, level
- Cheap insert, delete, move of the leaves
- Expensive insert, delete, move of the internal nodes

Here follows an example - taxonomic tree of birds so the hierarchy is Class/Order/Family/Genus/Species - species is the lowest level, 1 row = 1 taxon (which corresponds to species in the case of the leaf nodes):

```
CREATE TABLE `taxons` (
  `TaxonId` smallint(6) NOT NULL default '0',
  `ClassId` smallint(6) default NULL,
  `OrderId` smallint(6) default NULL,
  `FamilyId` smallint(6) default NULL,
  `GenusId` smallint(6) default NULL,
  `Name` varchar(150) NOT NULL default ''
);
```

and the example of the data:

```
+---------+---------+---------+----------+---------+-------------------------------+
| TaxonId | ClassId | OrderId | FamilyId | GenusId | Name                          |
+---------+---------+---------+----------+---------+-------------------------------+
|     254 |       0 |       0 |        0 |       0 | Aves                          |
|     255 |     254 |       0 |        0 |       0 | Gaviiformes                   |
|     256 |     254 |     255 |        0 |       0 | Gaviidae                      |
|     257 |     254 |     255 |      256 |       0 | Gavia                         |
|     258 |     254 |     255 |      256 |     257 | Gavia stellata                |
|     259 |     254 |     255 |      256 |     257 | Gavia arctica                 |
|     260 |     254 |     255 |      256 |     257 | Gavia immer                   |
|     261 |     254 |     255 |      256 |     257 | Gavia adamsii                 |
|     262 |     254 |       0 |        0 |       0 | Podicipediformes              |
|     263 |     254 |     262 |        0 |       0 | Podicipedidae                 |
|     264 |     254 |     262 |      263 |       0 | Tachybaptus                   |
```

This is great because this way you accomplish all the needed operations in a very easy way, as long as the internal categories don't change their level in the tree.

Answer (score 35):

This is a very partial answer to your question, but I hope still useful.

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 implements two features that are extremely useful for managing hierarchical data:

- the [HierarchyId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/bb677290.aspx) data type.
- common table expressions, using the [with](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) keyword.

Have a look at ["Model Your Data Hierarchies With SQL Server 2008"](https://web.archive.org/web/20081226162645/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc794278.aspx) by Kent Tegels on MSDN for starts. See also my own question: [Recursive same-table query in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1757370/)

Comment: Interesting, the HierarchyId, didn't know about that one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx

Comment: Indeed. I work with a lot of recursively hierarchical data, and I find common table expressions extremely useful. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx for an intro.

Answer (score 17):

If your database supports arrays, you can also implement a lineage column or materialized path as an array of parent ids.

Specifically with Postgres you can then use the set operators to query the hierarchy, and get excellent performance with GIN indices.  This makes finding parents, children, and depth pretty trivial in a single query.  Updates are pretty manageable as well.

I have a full write up of using [arrays for materialized paths](http://www.monkeyandcrow.com/blog/hierarchies_with_postgres/) if you're curious.

Answer (score 12):

This is really a square peg, round hole question.

If relational databases and SQL are the only hammer you have or are willing to use, then the answers that have been posted thus far are adequate. However, why not use a tool designed to handle hierarchical data? [Graph database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database) are ideal for complex hierarchical data.

The inefficiencies of the relational model along with the complexities of any code/query solution to map a graph/hierarchical model onto a relational model is just not worth the effort when compared to the ease with which a graph database solution can solve the same problem.

Consider a Bill of Materials as a common hierarchical data structure.

```
class Component extends Vertex {
    long assetId;
    long partNumber;
    long material;
    long amount;
};

class PartOf extends Edge {
};

class AdjacentTo extends Edge {
};
```

**Shortest path between two sub-assemblies**: Simple graph traversal algorithm. Acceptable paths can be qualified based on criteria.

**Similarity**: What is the degree of similarity between two assemblies? Perform a traversal on both sub-trees computing the intersection and union of the two sub-trees. The percent similar is the intersection divided by the union.

**Transitive Closure**: Walk the sub-tree and sum up the field(s) of interest, e.g. "How much aluminum is in a sub-assembly?"

Yes, you can solve the problem with SQL and a relational database. However, there are much better approaches if you are willing to use the right tool for the job.

Comment: This answer would be immensely more useful if the use cases demonstrated, or better yet contrasted, how to query a graph database with SPARQL for instance instead of SQL in an RDBMS.

Comment: SPARQL is relevant to RDF databases which are a subclass of the larger domain of graph databases. I work with InfiniteGraph which is not an RDF database and does not currently support SPARQL. InfiniteGraph supports several different query mechanisms: (1) a graph navigation API for setting up views, filters, path qualifiers and result handlers, (2) a complex graph path pattern matching language, and (3) Gremlin.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do Graph databases represent and persist node and edge data in-memory and on-disk such that traversing and pattern-matching the graph is so cheap and fast? …and why can’t we do that with good ol’ tables?

Comment: @Dai, Remember, everything is an abstraction. All you need is an abstraction that supports the operations you want to perform. A table is just one possible abstraction. An object/graph database gives you an incredibly rich abstraction that a good ol' table could never provide.

Comment: @djhallx I'm not asking about abstractions though - I'm asking about what _specific_ data-structures can be used for ideal persistence of graph data on-disk.

Comment: @dai My company, www.objectivity.com, uses a complex, federated data storage scheme. A federation (logical) contains database (D) which contain containers (C), which contain pages (P) which contain slots for objects (O). Each page (usually 8K bytes but can be bigger) contains an array of pointers to the start of an object on the page. Each block of object bytes contains some administrative information and then data bytes. On top of this storage scheme, we layer client-side caching and a query language. The query language supports complex database and graph analytics.

Comment: Check out: https://support.objectivity.com/sites/default/files/docs/ig/latest/index.html

Comment: @djhallx Thank you for the info, but that doens't tell me how you persist nodes and edges though - or how that structure means node pattern-matching and graph-traversal can be peformed efficiently.

Comment: Everything is an object of some type represented by the schema. Like I said, objects are stored on a page. Each object has some administrative information followed by the object data. The object data includes the values of each of the attribute of the specific type. Every object has an object id, or OID that is used to link objects together. A Person object can have a Lives-at edge attribute that will contain the OID of an Address object. Graph-navigational queries follow these connections. Using an abstraction, you have non-object edges and object edges. Objectivity supports massively scale.

Answer (score 10):

I am using PostgreSQL with closure tables for my hierarchies.
I have one universal stored procedure for the whole database:

```
CREATE FUNCTION nomen_tree() RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $_$
DECLARE
  old_parent INTEGER;
  new_parent INTEGER;
  id_nom INTEGER;
  txt_name TEXT;
BEGIN
-- TG_ARGV[0] = name of table with entities with PARENT-CHILD relationships (TBL_ORIG)
-- TG_ARGV[1] = name of helper table with ANCESTOR, CHILD, DEPTH information (TBL_TREE)
-- TG_ARGV[2] = name of the field in TBL_ORIG which is used for the PARENT-CHILD relationship (FLD_PARENT)
    IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || TG_ARGV[1] || ' (child_id,ancestor_id,depth) 
        SELECT $1.id,$1.id,0 UNION ALL
      SELECT $1.id,ancestor_id,depth+1 FROM ' || TG_ARGV[1] || ' WHERE child_id=$1.' || TG_ARGV[2] USING NEW;
    ELSE                                                           
    -- EXECUTE does not support conditional statements inside
    EXECUTE 'SELECT $1.' || TG_ARGV[2] || ',$2.' || TG_ARGV[2] INTO old_parent,new_parent USING OLD,NEW;
    IF COALESCE(old_parent,0) <> COALESCE(new_parent,0) THEN
      EXECUTE '
      -- prevent cycles in the tree
      UPDATE ' || TG_ARGV[0] || ' SET ' || TG_ARGV[2] || ' = $1.' || TG_ARGV[2]
        || ' WHERE id=$2.' || TG_ARGV[2] || ' AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM '
        || TG_ARGV[1] || ' WHERE child_id=$2.' || TG_ARGV[2] || ' AND ancestor_id=$2.id);
      -- first remove edges between all old parents of node and its descendants
      DELETE FROM ' || TG_ARGV[1] || ' WHERE child_id IN
        (SELECT child_id FROM ' || TG_ARGV[1] || ' WHERE ancestor_id = $1.id)
        AND ancestor_id IN
        (SELECT ancestor_id FROM ' || TG_ARGV[1] || ' WHERE child_id = $1.id AND ancestor_id <> $1.id);
      -- then add edges for all new parents ...
      INSERT INTO ' || TG_ARGV[1] || ' (child_id,ancestor_id,depth) 
        SELECT child_id,ancestor_id,d_c+d_a FROM
        (SELECT child_id,depth AS d_c FROM ' || TG_ARGV[1] || ' WHERE ancestor_id=$2.id) AS child
        CROSS JOIN
        (SELECT ancestor_id,depth+1 AS d_a FROM ' || TG_ARGV[1] || ' WHERE child_id=$2.' 
        || TG_ARGV[2] || ') AS parent;' USING OLD, NEW;
    END IF;
  END IF;
  RETURN NULL;
END;
$_$;
```

Then for each table where I have a hierarchy, I create a trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER nomenclature_tree_tr AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON nomenclature FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE nomen_tree('my_db.nomenclature', 'my_db.nom_helper', 'parent_id');
```

For populating a closure table from existing hierarchy I use this stored procedure:

```
CREATE FUNCTION rebuild_tree(tbl_base text, tbl_closure text, fld_parent text) RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'TRUNCATE ' || tbl_closure || ';
    INSERT INTO ' || tbl_closure || ' (child_id,ancestor_id,depth) 
        WITH RECURSIVE tree AS
      (
        SELECT id AS child_id,id AS ancestor_id,0 AS depth FROM ' || tbl_base || '
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT t.id,ancestor_id,depth+1 FROM ' || tbl_base || ' AS t
        JOIN tree ON child_id = ' || fld_parent || '
      )
      SELECT * FROM tree;';
END;
$$;
```

Closure tables are defined with 3 columns - ANCESTOR_ID, DESCENDANT_ID, DEPTH. It is possible (and I even advice) to store records with same value for ANCESTOR and DESCENDANT, and a value of zero for DEPTH. This will simplify the queries for retrieval of the hierarchy. And they are very simple indeed:

```
-- get all descendants
SELECT tbl_orig.*,depth FROM tbl_closure LEFT JOIN tbl_orig ON descendant_id = tbl_orig.id WHERE ancestor_id = XXX AND depth <> 0;
-- get only direct descendants
SELECT tbl_orig.* FROM tbl_closure LEFT JOIN tbl_orig ON descendant_id = tbl_orig.id WHERE ancestor_id = XXX AND depth = 1;
-- get all ancestors
SELECT tbl_orig.* FROM tbl_closure LEFT JOIN tbl_orig ON ancestor_id = tbl_orig.id WHERE descendant_id = XXX AND depth <> 0;
-- find the deepest level of children
SELECT MAX(depth) FROM tbl_closure WHERE ancestor_id = XXX;
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL now supports the JSON data type:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html